# If $A,B \in \mathcal{S}$ implies that $A \cup B \in \mathcal{S}$, is $\mathcal{S}$ closed over countable, or merely finite union?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> If $A,B \in \mathcal{S}$ implies that $A \cup B \in \mathcal{S}$, is $\mathcal{S}$ closed over countable, or merely finite union?

Clearly, $\mathcal{S}$ is closed over finite unions.

Is this closed over infinitely countable unions? If $\mathcal{S}$ has an infinite countable sequence of sets $A_n$, does the union ($\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_n$) necessarily exist in $\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: No. Let $S$ be the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$, noting that the union of two finite sets is finite again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. Consider, for example, the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb{N}$. Clearly, the union of two finite sets is finite, but the countable union
$$\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \{n\}$$
is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the closed set $A_n:= [1/n,1-1/n] \subset \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N} _{\ge 2}$.

For finite unions, i.e. $I \subset \mathbb{N}_{\ge 2}$ is finite,

$\cup A_{n\in I}$ is a closed set.

What Is  $\cup A_{n \in \mathbb{N} _{\ge 2}} $?